# Django modelform widget attributes replaced or disregarded

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I've been scratching my head over this for the last little while.  I have been able to change the modelfield's field queryset and widget attributes, well somewhat!

```
class InvoiceItemForm(ModelForm):
    UOM = forms.ChoiceField (choices =  site_defaults.UOM)

    class meta:
        model = InvoiceItem
        fields = ['name', 'costcode', 'rate', 'quantity',]
        labels = {'name': 'Item', 'rate': 'Cost Per Unit', 'quantity': 'Base Quantity'}
        widgets = {'UOM': forms.Select(choices = site_defaults.UOM )}

    def __init__(self, current_user, current_project, *args, **kwargs):
            ''' Rendering custom ModelForm '''
            super(InvoiceItemForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

            the_title = None

            the_instance = kwargs.get('instance', None)
            if the_instance:
                the_costcode = the_instance.costcode

                if the_costcode:
                    the_title = the_costcode.title

            self.fields['costcode'].queryset =  CostCode.objects.filter(project = current_project, item = 0)
            self.fields['costcode'].widget = forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'site-flex-select-large', 'value': the_title})
```

When this is rendered, the costcode field takes the right instance.  Also, the class is shown as site-flex-select-large, but the title is shown as the instance.id and not the_title which is the instance.title (a text field is displayed with value of 192 instead of the title of the invoice item).

Why is Django ignoring some changes and accepting some other changes to the field?

I'm not sure if it is a relevant detail or not, but the modelform is used in an inlineformset:

```
expenses_forms = self.InvoiceItem_InlineFormSet(instance = the_invoice, prefix='expenses', form_kwargs={'current_user': user, 'current_project': project})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A fields widget is not the place that you should be setting initial values for fields. You should set this in the "initial" kwarg to the form's `__init__` method, you can pass it to the call to super. You then can set the costcode widget in the Meta

```
class InvoiceItemForm(ModelForm):
    UOM = forms.ChoiceField (choices =  site_defaults.UOM)

    class Meta:
        model = InvoiceItem
        fields = ['name', 'costcode', 'rate', 'quantity',]
        labels = {'name': 'Item', 'rate': 'Cost Per Unit', 'quantity': 'Base Quantity'}
        widgets = {
            'UOM': forms.Select(choices = site_defaults.UOM ),
            'costcode': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'site-flex-select-large'})
        }

    def __init__(self, current_user, current_project, *args, **kwargs):
        the_instance = kwargs.get('instance', None)
        if the_instance:
            the_costcode = the_instance.costcode
            if the_costcode:
                initial = kwargs.get('initial', {})
                initial['costcode'] = the_costcode.title
                kwargs['initial'] = initial
        super(InvoiceItemForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

EDIT: like Willem says, the costcode field is a `TextInput` so it does not make sense to set a queryset attribute on it unless you change it to a select

Comment: Thank you Iain! It looks like what is doing all the weight-lifting is 'kwargs['initial'] = initial' followed by the call to super which uses the kwargs['initial'] to initialize it.  I did try to use self.fields['costcode'].initial as well, but that did not work.  I am curious to know how the default implementation is initializing the field if it does not use .initial attribute of the field, in case you'd know.

Answer (score 1):

The *value* is not taken from the `attrs`, it is taken from the value of that field. You can set the `.initial` attribute of the field, like:

```
    def __init__(self, current_user, current_project, *args, **kwargs):
        ''' Rendering custom ModelForm '''
        super(InvoiceItemForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        the_title = None
        the_instance = kwargs.get('instance', None)
        if the_instance:
            the_costcode = the_instance.costcode
            if the_costcode:
                the_title = the_costcode.title

        self.fields['costcode'].queryset =  CostCode.objects.filter(project=current_project, item=0)
        self.fields['costcode'].initial = the_title
        self.fields['costcode'].widget = forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'site-flex-select-large'})
```

That being said, by using a `TextInput`, it will, as far as I know, just ignore the `queryset`, and it will not properly validate the data. I think you better use a [**`Select`** widget [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.Select) here, and then use some CSS/JavaScript to make it searchable through text.

Comment: After I posted the question and before your kind answer, I did try to use 'self.fields['costcode'].initial = the_title'. However, it did not work.  @Iain Shelvington solution did work though.  I think what is doing all the weight-lifting is 'kwargs['initial'] = initial' followed by the call to super which uses the kwargs['initial'] to initialize it.

Comment: Also, the reason I had to change the widget for the costcode is that the costcode is a one-to-one field and is rendered as a select widget.  However, I wanted the user not to be able to choose or change a certain number of forms to always be rendered .  I could use .readonly on the field, but it still shows a select field the user cannot do anything about which is not a good UX in my opinion, so I decided to make it look like a text line.  If you know of another way to render the title as a line of  non-editable text, please do let us know.